# Opening new Window from an existing Window?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

How can I open a new window (`QWidget`) from an existing window, so that it stays open and doesn't close even if the old one does?

```
class Window : public QWidget {
    QPushButton *newWindow;
public:
    Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void on_newWindow_clicked();
};

Window::Window(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    newWindow = new QPushButton("New Window!", this);
    QObject::connect(newWindow, &QPushButton::clicked,
                     this, &Window::on_newWindow_clicked);
}

void Window::on_newWindow_clicked()
{
    Window w;
    w.show();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Window w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

The first window opens just fine with the `newWindow` button displayed on it.
If I press the button, it will open a new window as expected, but it just flashes on the screen, closing instantly after being opened.

Also, since I need it so that I can close the original window and still keep the new window open, should I use multiple processes and/or threads for this?

Comment: C++ basics, your `Window mw;` is going to be destroyed at the end of the scope...

Comment: @peppe Yes, I am well aware of that. That's exactly why I'm asking how to make it not get destroyed.

Comment: Don't allocate it on the stack! Use `Window *mw = new Window; mw->show();` instead. Preventing a possible next question ;-) you may want to set `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` on such window, or manage its lifetime through the `mw` pointer.

Comment: @peppe Hey! It's been a long time, but I'm searching through my questions and found this one. If you want some free points, make that an answer and I'll accept it :)